# What does 'schema' refer to in AWS Database Migration Service (DMS) if source database is S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-dms

I'm trying to transfer a test csv file from S3 to DynamoDB table using AWS Database Migration Service. I'm new to aws so forgive me if I'm doing something completely wrong.

I've created and tested source & target endpoints with no problem. However, I've run into some task definition errors (I'm not sure why but my logs don't appear in CloudWatch).

For simplicity's sake, my test source S3 file has only one column: `eventId`. The path is as follows: `s3://myBucket/testFolder/events/events.csv`

This is a JSON external definition file:

```
{
    "TableCount": "1",
    "Tables": [
        {
            "TableName": "events",
            "TablePath": "testFolder/events/",
            "TableOwner": "testFolder",
            "TableColumns": [
                {
                    "ColumnName": "eventId",
                    "ColumnType": "STRING",
                    "ColumnNullable": "false",
                    "ColumnIsPk": "true",
                    "ColumnLength": "10",
                }
            ],
            "TableColumnsTotal": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's my task definition:

```
  "rules": [
   {
      "rule-type": "selection",
      "rule-id": "1",
      "rule-name": "1",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "testFolder",
        "table-name": "events"
      },
      "rule-action": "include"
    },
    {
      "rule-type": "object-mapping",
      "rule-id": "2",
      "rule-name": "2",
      "rule-action": "map-record-to-record",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "testFolder",
        "table-name": "tableName"

      },
      "target-table-name": "myTestDynamoDBTable",
      "mapping-parameters": {
        "partition-key-name": "eventId",
        "attribute-mappings": [
          {
            "target-attribute-name": "eventId",
            "attribute-type": "scalar",
            "attribute-sub-type": "string",
            "value": "${eventId}"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Every time, my task is errored. I'm particularly confused about schema as my source file is in S3 so I thought schema is not needed there? I found this line in AWS docs:

`s3://mybucket/hr/employee. At load time, AWS DMS assumes that the source schema name is hr...` -> So should I include some sort of schema file in the hr folder?

Apologies if this is wrong, I'd appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Comment: In your case, according to the docs, schema is implicitly `hr` and source table name is implicitly `employee`. Can you share any error messages?